# Microstrategy Clustering and licences

Tags: business-intelligence, microstrategy

I have two registered instance of MSTG 9.3 suite, both with 10 named user licences. I have used one in testing and second in production purpose. I want to create MSTG cluster. Would I get 10+10 named user licences or I will 'lose' 10 licences?

Thanks,
Stevan

Answer (score 0):

You should talk with your MicroStrategy Sales guy.

I'm not sure if you need a new licence key for the cluster or if the test user licences are cheaper than the prod ones.

If you have 20 named user licenses you should be entitle to use 20 user on multiple servers, but the licence key on the server should allow 20 named users. So for sure you need a new licence key.